# Error consuming wcf service in web app

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I am trying to consume a wcf service. I can consume the web service using a console app. but when I try to consume the service using a web app, I get a ssl/ tls error. I hav installed the certificate that was given to me by the administrator.

Is there any thing different that I need to do in with my web app?

Comment: Providing the full error message would be great.....

Comment: What type of security are you using?